# Is there a solution to allow implementation of an abstraction layer using generics over several similar types with different interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, abstraction

Suppose you have several types each representing a collection of fields.
Each type's fields are different, but some types share some fields.

Let us consider IceCream types. All IceCream types implement a common interface which requires that a method, getFlavor() be exposed. However, each IceCream type also exposes several other methods. IceCream types include things like Gelato, WaterIce, FrozenCustard, ChilledCream, and Traditional

Some IceCream types expose a method to get the manufacturer, but other IceCream types have no manufacturer and thus do not expose a method for getting the manufacturer.

Further, the IceCream types do not expose the getManufacturer() method in the same way - some call it getManufacturer(), while others call it getMaker(), getChef(), or getOwner(). Additionally, a single IceCream type may have multiple separate methods that each return the same (or different) manufacturers.

Given some set of IceCream types, some with methods that return a manufacturer (the manufacturer will always be the same data type) how might one abstract over these IceCream types so that they can write generic logic for dealing with the IceCream types instead of duplicating all of the code that is used to retrieve the manufacturer for every IceCream type separately?

Unfortunately, these classes cannot be modified.

It seems like this would require some kind of enumeration containing a mapping from Type -> String, and the Strings are used to reflectively resolve the class methods. Is there another generic way to implement this?

Comment: I suggest you to use decorator pattern.

For each type of ice cream, you need to create an IceCreamDecorator.
The decorator will implement two interfaces which are IIceCream and IIceCreamManufactor and you pass the icecream as an innerclass. The IIceCreamManufactor has one method which is getManufactor so this will encapsulate getMaker(), getChef(), or getOwner() of the inner class. This way you are not changing the existing code and you are free to extend the decorator as you will.

Comment: if you like it..can I create a new answer with it and you mark it as the answer?:P Just want to get some points!!

Comment: Sure! I think it's a decent answer - using a decorator to contain a broken abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use decorator pattern. For each type of ice cream, you need to create an `IceCreamDecorator`. The decorator will implement two interfaces which are `IIceCream` and `IIceCreamManufactor` and you pass the `icecream` as an innerclass. The `IIceCreamManufactor` has one method which is `getManufactor` so this will encapsulate `getMaker()`, `getChef()`, or `getOwner()` of the inner class. This way you are not changing the existing code and you are free to extend the decorator as you will.

Answer (score 0):

If you could change the existing IceCream types you could introduce a new interface.

As that is not possible, the next best option would be to a dedicated class for each of "fields"; like a class `ManufactorerRetriever`. For that example, this class knows the different IceCream types - and how to retrieve the actual manufacturer for the different types. This allows you to at least contain all these ugly "instanceof" calls in a central spot.

Comment: What if we need to do another non-generic thing with the IceCream based on its manufacturer? Do we just build additional cross-cutting abstraction classes over some component of IceCream's functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default implementation in the interface from Java 8, so if there is no manufacture than not required to implement it. Or you can use a base abstract class that implements some base methods and it can hold some basic interface implementation what will required to implement. It is very hard to find a good solution for these kind of abstraction because everything can be varies in the future.

Comment: Can't change the existing types.